# How to send an email when the workflow doesnt start in Informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter, control-m

I have a workflow which gets triggered everyday in the Morning at 07:15 AM by the Control-M(Scheduling tool).I want to get an email to my Id from Informatica when the workflow doesn't get trigerred within 3 min from the start time.

Comment: You should tag this as control-m given thats where the answer most likely lies... I could make a suggestion on Informatica code which would work but most likely control m has an elegant way of handling this (some sort of dependency to only run a job at a particular time if some other job hasn't ran yet)

Answer (score 0):

In the Control-M job that starts your Informatica Workflow you can configure a shout to to run if the job hasn't started/completed by 07:18. You can additionally configure this shout to go to a custom shout destination.
You will need to define this custom shout destination through the `Shout Destinations Manager` in `Configuration Manager`.
A custom shout destination can be defined to pass some variables to an email script for example.

Comment: Does the same apply for the cyclic job? Actually this job runs every 90 minutes daily between 07:15 AM to 10:00 PM, i.e., 07:15 AM, 08:45 AM, 10:15 AM ..........08:45 PM. So my job if its doesnt start by 3 min from the scheduled start time, the email alarm  should be sent

Comment: To cater for a cyclic job you would have to set up a second job that shares an exclusive `Control Resource` with your primary job. Assuming your workflow job executes for >4 min you could set this second job to run cyclically every 90 min with a 3 min offset start time and a tolerance of 1 min. This means that this job will only run if the workflow job is not executing between 07:18-07:19 etc.
However this is all overkill and we aren't addressing the root cause. A Control-M job should always start at its defined times - in the past what has stopped it from starting when it was meant to??